# Unable to extract uploader_id

Tags: python, youtube-dl

```py
import youtube_dl

def download_youtube_video(url):
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestvideo+bestaudio/best',
        'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        try:
            info_dict = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
            video_title = info_dict.get('title', None)
            print(f"Downloaded '{video_title}' successfully!")
        except Exception as e:
            print("An error occurred during the download:")
            print(str(e))

video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWxB9yiYAgo'
download_youtube_video(video_url)
```

This returns:
ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

What am I missing here?

I tried changing the structure of the code a few times. Calling YouTube_dl with the link itself and nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`youtube-dl` is out of date. Since YouTube tends to change pretty often, YTDL must be kept up to date, otherwise errors like this crop up.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by upgrading the library using:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall "git+https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently created a youtube downloader tkinter-based application and faced the same problem.

Since youtube-dl is outdated, we have to use its up-to-date fork called yt-dlp.
Make sure it is installed otherwise, run: *pip install yt-dlp*

Here is the working code:

```
import yt_dlp

url = "<<your video url>>"

video_info = yt_dlp.YoutubeDL().extract_info(url, download = False)
title = video_info.get("title", "YouTube video")
```

In this example, we extract a video's title. If for some reason it is not provided, we use the default title "YouTube video". With the same method we can extract information such as "fps" ...